# Statistics of Stack Exchange Project (Code Metrics)

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, statistics

Is there a collection of statistics about the Stack Exchange Project available?
Things I had in mind are along the lines of:

- Code Metrics (Lines of Code)
- Usage statistics (like page requests per day)
- Content metrics (number of questions / answers)

Especially the first bullet point is something I would like to know about, so if there is no official data available, reasoned estimates are also appreciated.

Comment: I think your first bullet is not a *GLOBAL* issue for all SE sites ;).

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer as it doesn't tell you the number of lines of code in the Stack Exchange site, however usage statistics and content metrics are available on the Stack Exchange [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) page.

[image: Usage and question/answer totals]s

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed that one before! :)